# How to check for the form values that already exist in db before inserting it into database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

And Validation is for checking whether the form values where already inserted into db.

And It will be good If the coding were related to laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the laravel unique validator to validate the input.

```
$data = Input::all();
$validator = Validator::make($data, ['Pid' => 'unique:addProducts,Pid']);
if ($validator->fails())
  ...
```

or

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'Pid' => 'unique:addProducts,Pid'
]);
```

Comment: public function addProduct(Request $form1) {
      $temp=new addModel;
      $temp->Pid="GC".$form1->input('Pid');
      $temp->Pname=$form1->input('Pname');
      $temp->save();
 }

Comment: That was my insertion coding. And there I need to validate whether the Pid is already exists in db which is entered by the user

Comment: What's your table naem???

Comment: addProducts is my table name

Comment: I mean the table name in the database, not the model name

Comment: Yes sir,I am mentioning that only. The table name of my database is addProducts

Answer (score 0):

Use a form request to validate the user's input before it reaches your controller's logic. It will return useful error messages to the user pertaining to the invalid fields. You can even customize the authorization access a user has to a given route/resource. See the docs here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation

If you want to validate before the user submits the form, you will need to send an ajax request to the server first.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function validateMe(Request $request){
   $this->validate($request,[
                  'id'=>'required|unique://your table name here']);
   return redirect()->back();

}
and you can call the error with this 
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```